# Show the additional clock in Task bar

Tags: windows-7

I have setup an additional clock (from the Date and time settings). I would like Windows 7 to display the additional clock time in the task bar. In effect, I would be able to see the time of both the clocks from the task bar time and date area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **click on the time** in the taskbar and then you'll see both times.
But having both clocks directly without click is not possible.

[image]

Comment: with out clicking on the time i should get the time of system and San Francisco